# SharedPreferences for login in android

Tags: android, authentication, sharedpreferences

I am working on the android application that required login. I want to check when user press the PostIdea activity button then check the user logged in or not, if not then redirect to the login page else continue with the task.

Here I am using SharedPreferences for that. Now when I press the login button then username & password add to the SharedPreferences and when press the PostIdea Activity then I got the  username & password.

**BUT my problem** is that when I restart the application and go the PostIdea Activity without login then it remember the last login(username/password) of SharedPreferences data.How can I remove that data from SharedPreferences,so that my application works correctly.         Let me know where I do mistake or there is any other solution for my problem.

Thanks.

LoginActivity.class

```
public class LoginActivity extends CheerfoolznativeActivity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    setHeader("Login");

    editUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_useredit);
    editPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_passedit);
    txterror = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);
    textlogin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_postidea_textView);
    btngotoregister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
    btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    pgb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.login_progressBar);

    btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new Login().execute();

        }
    });

}

public class Login extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    int i = 0;
    String uName ;
    String Password;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

        uName = editUser.getText().toString().trim();
        Password = editPass.getText().toString().trim();

        if (uName.equals("") | Password.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter the Data",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (editUser.length() == 0) {
                editUser.setError("Enter Username");
            }
            if (editPass.length() == 0) {
                editPass.setError("Enter Password");
            }
        } else {

            pgb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            String loginURL = "http://www.cheerfoolz.com/rest/user/login";

            strResponse = util.makeWebCall(loginURL, uName, Password);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    txterror.setText("");

            try {
                if (strResponse.substring(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    txterror.setText("");

                    // SharedPreferences Logic
                    SharedPreferences userDetails =getSharedPreferences("userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    Editor edit = userDetails.edit();
                    edit.clear();
                    edit.putString("username", uName);
                    edit.putString("password", Password);
                    edit.commit();


                    new FetchUserProfileTask().execute();

                } else {
                    txterror.setText("Username and Password Not valid !!!");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

    }

}

public class FetchUserProfileTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    int i = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();


    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        //logic for the featch user profile data

    return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

         pgb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        displayProfile();

    }
}

public void displayProfile() {

    Intent in1 = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, post_myprofile.class);
    in1.putExtra("loginObject", bean);
    startActivity(in1);
}

}
```

Post_idea_Activity.class

```
public class Post_idea_Activity extends CheerfoolznativeActivity {

TextView txtwelcome;
String Uname="";
String pass = ""; 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    SharedPreferences userDetails = getSharedPreferences("userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
    System.out.println("value of the userdertails ==========>"+ userDetails);
    //String Uname="";
    //String pass= ""; 

    Uname = userDetails.getString("username", "");
    pass = userDetails.getString("password", "");

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"username : "+Uname +" \n password :"+pass, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (Uname.equals(null)) 
    {
        Intent in1 = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        in1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(in1);

    }
    else {

        setContentView(R.layout.post_idea);
        setHeader("Post idea");

        txtwelcome =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.post_welcome_text);
             }


       }

   //  coding for the layout
}
```

Comment: You mean to say you don't want to remember the user name and password, and you wish user to provide credentials every time they take application in foreground? is this you want?

Comment: "BUT my problem is that when I restart the application and go the PostIdea Activity without login then it remember the last login(username/password) of SharedPreferences data." Personally, that's exactly the behavior I want from an Android app. I want it to remember my user-name and password. Remember only one person tends to use an android device ... this seems standard behavior in other apps.

Comment: you want to clear the shared preference data in splash screen?

Comment: What you want to implement exactly? Want to remember username/password for further use or want to clear everytime you start application?

Comment: Thanks,Yes I want to clear the username and password when restart application.It required remember after the login.

Comment: @PareshMayani Thanks, I want to clear it before login.after login its remember up to the Logout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear your shared preferences when your app starts.

```
SharedPreferences userDetails =getSharedPreferences("userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor edit = userDetails.edit();
edit.clear();
edit.commit();
```

You can write this in Application class of your application.

Comment: Thanks,Using that clear the username and password ,but how can I pass intent to the login page when press the postIdea button without login,I tried this one.    SharedPreferences userDetails = getSharedPreferences("userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
  Uname = userDetails.getString("username", "");
  pass = userDetails.getString("password", "");
  
  if (Uname.equals(null)) 
  {
   Intent in1 = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
   startActivity(in1);
      
  }
  else {      
   setContentView(R.layout.post_idea);
   setHeader("Post idea");
   
  }

Comment: you should check if(Uname.equals(""))

Comment: I have implemented home button in viewstub header,That redirect to the main page where I put above code.so after login when I press the home button and at the same time shared preferences data(username) is cleared.so login user session also gets cleared.I want to maintain login user's session.Please help me with the solution.

Comment: where have you written the above code? Extend Application class and write the code in that class.

Comment: I have already put this code in my application(Main) class and postIdea class extend to the application class. when press the home button after login then redirect to the application class then shared prefernces data become clear.

Answer (score 2):

clear the shared prefernce in the splash screen use the below code in splash screen that means first activity of your application

```
SharedPreferences userDetails =getSharedPreferences("userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    Editor edit = userDetails.edit();
                    edit.clear();
                    edit.putString("username", "");
                    edit.putString("password", "");
                    edit.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks,but I have not implemented splash screen yet now.

Comment: then use this this shared preferences before starting of the login activity

Answer (score 1):

```
    Write in login page.....
    //variables
    String PREFS_USER_ID = "USER_ID";
    String  PREF_NAME = "Pref";
    String  USER_ID;
    //write in where u want to store data....
    setPreferences(PREF_NAME, PREFS_USER_ID, USER_ID);
    // methods
    private void setPreferences(String preferenceName, String key, String value)
    {
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(preferenceName, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString(key, value);
            editor.commit();
    }
    private String getSharedPreferences(String preferenceName, String key)
    {
            // Restore preferences
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(preferenceName, 0);
            String value = settings.getString(key, null);
            return value;
    }
    in the other activity u get user name and password.........
    String userid=getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PREFS_USER_ID);
    //method
    private String getSharedPreferences(String preferenceName, String key)
    {
        // Restore preferences
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(preferenceName, 0);
            String value = settings.getString(key, null);
            return value;
    }
// for delete  or remove the data from sharepreferences
SharedPreferences wmbPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = wmbPreference.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks, but its not workig.I have put code for remove date from sharedprefernces into my main activity.