# The application has stopped unexpectedly ~

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

So I am following the user login and registration walkthrough at http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-login-and-registration-screen-design/ (for at the moment before we get the database actually up) and I have everything in place with no errors in eclipse. Can someone please take a look at my code and tell me what's causing the app to stop unexpectedly? Thanks in advance!
LoginActivity.java

```
    package com.example.loginactivity;

     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.content.Intent;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.TextView;


     public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setting default screen to login.xml
    setContentView(com.example.loginactivity.R.layout.login);


    TextView registerScreen = (TextView) findViewById(com.example.loginactivity.R.id.link_to_register);

    // Listening to register new account link
    registerScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Switching to Register screen
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Register.java

```
    package com.example.loginactivity;


    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;


public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Set View to register.xml
    setContentView(com.example.loginactivity.R.layout.register);

    TextView loginScreen = (TextView) findViewById(com.example.loginactivity.R.id.link_to_login);

    // Listening to Login Screen link
    loginScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            // Closing registration screen
            // Switching to Login Screen/closing register screen
            finish();
        }
    });
}
}
```

login.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true">
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#ffffff">

    <!--  Header  Starts-->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@layout/header_gradient"
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip">
            <!-- Logo Start-->
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>
            <!-- Logo Ends -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <!--  Header Ends -->
    <!-- Footer Start -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dip"
            android:background="@layout/footer_repeat"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Footer Ends -->

    <!-- Login Form -->
    <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="10dip"
      android:layout_below="@id/header">
      <!--  Email Label -->
      <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#372c24"
            android:text="Email"/>
      <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
            android:singleLine="true"/>
      <!--  Password Label -->
      <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#372c24"
            android:text="Password"/>
      <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:password="true"/>
      <!-- Login button -->
      <Button android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:text="Login"/>
      <!-- Link to Registration Screen -->
      <TextView android:id="@+id/link_to_register"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dip"
            android:text="New to Twitter? Register here"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:textColor="#0b84aa"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Login Form Ends -->
  </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Register.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true">
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#fff">

    <!--  Header  Starts-->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@layout/header_gradient"
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip">
            <!-- Logo Start-->
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>
            <!-- Logo Ends -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <!--  Header Ends -->
    <!-- Footer Start -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dip"
            android:background="@layout/footer_repeat"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Footer Ends -->

    <!-- Registration Form -->
    <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="10dip"
      android:layout_below="@id/header">
      <!-- Full Name Label -->
      <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#372c24"
            android:text="Full Name"/>
      <EditText android:id="@+id/reg_fullname"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"/>
      <!--  Email Label -->
      <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#372c24"
            android:text="Email"/>
      <EditText android:id="@+id/reg_email"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"/>
      <!-- Password Label -->
      <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#372c24"
            android:text="Password"/>
      <EditText android:id="@+id/reg_password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:password="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"/>
      <!-- Register Button -->
      <Button android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:text="Register New Account"/>
      <!-- Link to Login Screen -->
      <TextView android:id="@+id/link_to_login"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dip"
            android:text="Already has account! Login here"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:textColor="#025f7c"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Registration Form Ends -->
  </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Here is the logcat:

```
    08-26 17:21:14.818: D/AndroidRuntime(17713): Shutting down VM
08-26 17:21:14.818: W/dalvikvm(17713): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception       (group=0x4001d5a0)
08-26 17:21:14.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17713): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-26 17:21:14.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17713): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate  activity ComponentInfo{com.example.loginactivity/com.example.loginactivity.MainActivity}:  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.loginactivity.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.loginactivity-2.apk]
08-26 17:21:14.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17713):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1746)
08-26 17:21:14.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17713):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1854)
08-26 17:21:14.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17713):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-26 17:21:14.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17713):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1041)
08-26 17:21:14.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17713):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-26 17:21:14.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17713):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
08-26 17:21:14.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17713):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4333)
08-26 17:21:14.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17713):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-26 17:21:14.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17713):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 08-26 17:21:14.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17713):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-26 17:21:14.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17713):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-26 17:21:14.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17713):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-26 17:21:14.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17713): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.loginactivity.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.loginactivity-2.apk]
08-26 17:21:14.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17713):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
08-26 17:21:14.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17713):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
08-26 17:21:14.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17713):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
08-26 17:21:14.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17713):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1040)
08-26 17:21:14.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17713):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1738)
08-26 17:21:14.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17713):    ... 11 more
```

Here is the AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.loginactivity"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.loginactivity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
   <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
              android:label="Login to your Account">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!--  Entry for RegisterActivity.class -->
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"
              android:label="Register New Account"></activity>

</application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: Please capture and paste the logcat!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**update:**

the problem is that the activity is not registered in the manifest.

Please add your Activity in your AndroidManifest.xml.

When you want to making new activity, you should register it in your AndroidManifest.xml.

ex.

```
    <activity
        android:name="x.x.x.Register"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.REGISTER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.loginactivity"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

   <application 
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity android:name="com.example.loginactivity.LoginActivity"
              android:label="Login to your Account">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

       <activity
            android:name="com.example.loginactivity.RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.REGISTERACTIVITY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

</application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: Using `com.example.loginactivity.R.layout.login` is perfectly fine(although redundant). You can see from the user's question: Package name is `com.example.loginactivity`. And `R` is _indeed_ `com.example.loginactivity.R`. Also, using `getApplicationContext()` in an Intent is legit.

Comment: I should have it in the Maniefest.xml correctly...I'll add it on.

Comment: I'm running it on my mom's android phone if that would help any but I do have everything set up correctly on it and all the driver software downloaded on my computer..

Comment: Thanks, I'll let you know if this fixes it

Comment: Ok yes that fixed it. Just wondering since I'm kind of new to android app making what do you mean when you say "two <application> none exist maniactivty" just for future reference.

Comment: ok thanks again ^.^/) Now just to move onto building the actual database :)